# Selenium WebDriver page object navigation best practice

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, helper, pageobjects

Mostly I implement frameworks using Page Object/Page Factory approach base on Java and I would like to improve my existing codebase.

My questions are:

- My methods are returning page objects.(return PageFactory.initelements(...)); I have read some comments, it is not the best approach because all the tests depends on the framework developer. I'm sure, generic methods would be better! Any suggestion?
- Navigation modules are common on every page, so my idea was that using helper/utility class in order to reach the common navigation methods easily. Common static methods is the proper way to achieve the 'do not repeat yourself goal'? Why should I repeat all of the navigation methods on every page object?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1. I use the page object model also but never implemented the returning of page objects. I don't know... I just never liked that idea. I don't think it's necessarily bad, I think it just means that you have to create more methods that do the same thing. You have to do two of a lot of methods, one for intended success and one for intended fail, e.g. `Login()` and `FailedLogin()`.

Q2. Page objects don't have to be pages. I have header and footer page objects that contain the header and footer navigation links, etc. The parts of the page that are repeated on multiple pages go in the header page object. Whenever I get to any page and need something in the header area, I instantiate the header page object and use it.

Comment: Hi JeffC, Thanks! Q2: its a good idea but how can I achieve it? I have BasePage with instantiations (webdriver, database connector etc) and some common methods eg. customClick, selects, list handlers using custom wait methods etc. Every pageobject extends BasePage. How cna I use the navigation object which is common on every page? Should it extend the basePage? Any idea would be appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you have a lot more in your page object than you should. Remember, the page object should contain things related to the page in question. It shouldn't contain things like common methods, database connectors, and the like. Those should be in some Utils class elsewhere so it can be called when needed. You might post your code over at codereview.stackexchange.com and get some feedback there.

Comment: @brobee if you post on CR, make sure to include all your code. CR only reviews real code, not example code.

Comment: Jeff, all of my pageobjects are represents only the particular page. I mentioned the basepage, which is the top of the abstraction and every page extend it. Utils class are mostly static classes with static methods and I heard that its a bad concept thats why I didn't create static methods for navigation. So utils class make sense for common navigation in this case? Thanks! I cannot copy paste my code unfortunately..

Comment: When your page objects inherit the basepage, then they take on those methods. The basepage should not contain the things I listed above. Methods that don't represent some action on the page should not be in a page object but should instead be in some Utils class. There's nothing wrong with static classes... many common libraries have Utils classes. Common navigation I addressed in my answer.